# What do you call a growth factor?

Tags: terminology

This is just a question about terminology for a document I'm writing.

- (Simple) return: $X_{t+1}/X_t - 1$
- Log return: $\log\left(X_{t+1}/X_t\right)$
- ???: $X_{t+1}/X_t$

I was thinking "growth factor" maybe? But it has to have a better name.

Comment: I do like (and use) the expression "growth factor" because it is widely understood by many different people. In statistics it is sometimes called the "link relative" but that is not widely known outside of economic statistics. In Finance it is sometimes called the "gross return", so $r$ is the simple return and $(1+r)$ is the "gross return". Take your pick.

Comment: It's also frequently called growth rate - see Wikipedia's page for [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean#Average_growth_rate).